# Python : Split a list of length n into a table or further lists, by type, retaining order

Tags: python, list

Essentially I have a list of items each with a different type such as

```
['a',1,'b',2,3,'c']
```

or

```
[{"A":1},1,{"B":2},{"C":3},"a"]
```

and I would like to split these into two seperate lists, retaining the original order

```
[[ 'a', None,  'b', None, None,  'c'],
 [None,    1, None,    2,    3, None]]
```

or

```
[[{"A":1}, None, {"B":2},{"C":3}, None],
 [None,       1,    None,   None, None],
 [None,    None,    None,   None,  "a"]]
```

What I have :

```
def TypeSplit(sources)
  Types = [dict(),str(),num()]
  return [[item for item in sources if type(item) == type(itype)] for itype in types]
```

Though this doesn't fill in `None`.

The reason I'm doing this is that I will be given a list with different types of info and need to flesh it out with other values that compliment the original list.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: In truth my actual data set is limited to filenames and dicts, everything else is discarded. The dicts require filenames and the files are read and dicts are returned. I deliberately made the question more generic to get a verstile answer for anyone else with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use-case for the conditional expression. Also, I'm assuming you'd like to do this in as generalized a way as possible, so instead of using a fixed list of types, I'd suggest generating the list dynamically:

```
def type_split(sources):
    types = sorted(set(type(i) for i in sources))
    return [[item if type(item) == itype else None for item in sources] 
            for itype in types]
```

If you need to use a fixed list (and you know that your input list won't contain anything but those types and their subclasses), you could do this:

```
import collections
import numbers
def type_split(sources):
    types = [basestring, collections.Mapping, numbers.Number]
    return [[item if isinstance(item, itype) else None for item in sources] 
            for itype in types]
```

Comment: Instead of `type(item) == type(itype)`, you should probably use `isinstance(item,itype)`

Comment: doing a `set` of the types is a good idea except you don't know which (sub)list contains the integers and which contains the dictionaries, etc, etc.

Comment: Dang it, I thought the only way to do conditionals in iterators was as [item for item in items if condition], my apologies for the silly question.

Comment: @Carel -- this is sometimes called the ternary operator -- and it is much better in python than it is in C (`i=(x>0)?1:-1` -- Yuck!)

Answer (score 2):

I might take a slightly different approach here using a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def type_split(sources):
   d=defaultdict(lambda : [None]*len(sources))
   for i,src in enumerate(sources):
       d[type(src)][i] = src
   return d
```

This returns a dictionary instead of a list, but it is easier to introspect the types of the various elements...If you really want the list of lists, you can always just look at `d.values()` (in python2.x) or `list(d.values())` in python 3.x

Comment: Nice -- this produces the sought-after parallel structure in a clever way.

Comment: Exactly how I've just done it and was about to post - oh well :) Definitely the simplest and most generic answer here though...

Comment: @JonClements -- I don't know about simplest.  The `lambda : [None]*len(sources)` is a bit ugly.

Comment: Well, it's the simplest in that I can't OTTTOMH think of any other way to write it?

Comment: @JonClements -- There's the other list-comp solutions ;-).  But I do think this is the simplest way to do it with a dict (at least that I can think of as well).  I suppose it could be done with a regular dict and `setdefault` as well, but less efficiently...

Comment: @jamylak, I doubt this is more efficient than the list comprehension; it's still O(ntypes * nvals). It's just that the quadratic part is hidden in the `lambda`. I just like this because it produces a nice `dict`.

Comment: You should do this instead: `d = OrderedDict((type(x), [None]*len(seq)) for x in seq)` @senderle Alright I agree but I should do some timings first

Comment: @jamylak -- That way creates a list of len(seq) for every item in seq -- many of them are generated just to be thrown away.  It does have the advantage that it keeps order (although the order here isn't well defined as it is the order the elements show up) and disadvantage that it relies on python2.7 or an activestate recipe whereas mine goes back to python 2.5.  Ultimately, I provided this solution not for efficiency or anything -- just because I thought it was a better data structure.

Comment: @mgilson I agree that it is not as efficient but if you are not providing this solution for efficiency like you just said, it would be a better data structure (for later python versions).

Comment: @jamylak -- What makes the data structure better?  Both are dictionaries.  Yours is ordered, but ordered by the order in which a particular type appears in the input list (which isn't well defined as far as I can tell.).  I guess my question is why define a set order if it is more or less random anyway?

Comment: @mgilson I assumed that the items are in the order that they appear since that was true for both examples.

Comment: @mgilson http://stackoverflow.com/a/11651554/1219006 This does the same thing as yours and keeps order

Comment: @jamylak -- I saw (it's a reasonably good answer).  But it also creates a list at every node of `seq` most of which are thrown away.  This is basically the same thing that I was proposing in my comment to JonClements (except without the OrderedDict).  Ultimately I don't know that the order matters as the order in the "desired" solution by the OP differs from the order in the attempted solution by the OP.  I'm guessing that the OP will be happy as long as there is a well defined way to access the desired list.

Comment: I was hoping to retain the order of the original input list once I'd filled in the none's I then regroup everything ie [dict,string] becomes [[none string],[dict,none] becomes [[new string, string],[dict,new dict]] becomes [[new string, dict][string, new dict]]. My attempt was no good as I lost the input order, which I need to temporarily retain while filling in the unknowns.

Comment: @Carel -- the order inside the *sublists* will be maintained.  i.e. input `['a',1]` will result in two lists:  `['a', None]` and `[None, 1]` in all of our solutions.  The thing we're debating is how do you get a handle in the list `['a', None]`?  With your list comprehension it would be something like `masterlist[1]`, with my way it is something like `masterdict[str]`.  With the solution by jamylak it is either: `masterlist[str]` or `list(masterlist.values())[1]`.  Does that make sense?  In either case, you can do what you want with filling in the unknowns.

Comment: If I pre-order the types I look for I may know the order of the lists but some one using my output would not unless they looked at the code. Putting it into a dict I explicitly name the type of each set. Though it gets messy in the sense of an ordered dict that is generated by the type order of the items in the input list i.e. [{},''] differs from ['',{}] so an unordered dict is then better as it doesn't care from the start.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def type_split(seq, types): 
        return [[x if isinstance(x, t) else None for x in seq] for t in types]

>>> type_split(['a',1,'b',2,3,'c'], (str, int))
[['a', None, 'b', None, None, 'c'], [None, 1, None, 2, 3, None]]
>>> type_split([{"A":1},1,{"B":2},{"C":3},"a"], (dict, int, str))
[[{'A': 1}, None, {'B': 2}, {'C': 3}, None], [None, 1, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, 'a']]
```

Comment: why is this inefficient ? I can't see an obvious reason.

Comment: @Carel my bad, It's not actually inefficient but it calculates `isinstance` more times then necessary although it's probably a very fast calculation.

Comment: Is there a way of skipping the isinstance test ? I can't think of an instance of getting past this, if one knew they were targeting a certain type you could test for just that type, but that would still require testing each element.

Comment: @Carel You only have to test `isinstance` once for each item, you just fill the other rows with `None`. This solution was made for it's small size and it really should be fine for most situations.

Comment: Oh I just clicked, N Items and M types => MxN tests instead of N tests, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An adaptation of the solution by @mgilson which keeps original order of types as ordered keys.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> def type_split(seq):
        d = OrderedDict()
        for i, x in enumerate(seq):
            d.setdefault(type(x), [None] * len(seq))[i] = x
        return d.values()

>>> type_split(['a',1,'b',2,3,'c'])
[['a', None, 'b', None, None, 'c'], [None, 1, None, 2, 3, None]]
>>> type_split([{"A":1},1,{"B":2},{"C":3},"a"])
[[{'A': 1}, None, {'B': 2}, {'C': 3}, None], [None, 1, None, None, None], [None, None, None, None, 'a']]
```

Comment: I still don't believe that the order matters here, but +1 for showing how you can achieve it in the event that order does matter.